# Different colors in matpotlib bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, nan

I calculated NaN value percentage of a dataframe and then plotted it. I want each variable to have a unique color. The code I used works well but every 9th variable color is same as 1st variable color, and the cycle repeats. See the pic:

[image: NaN Values]

The code:

```
per = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 12), dpi = 200)
i = 0
for key, value in zip(per.keys(), per.values):
    if (value > 0):
        ax.bar(key, value, label=key)
        ax.text(i, value + 0.5, str(np.round(value, 2)), ha='center')
        i = i + 1
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([]) 
plt.title('NaN Value percentage in the dataset')
plt.ylim(0,115)
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I tried the following line of code, but it picked only first color:

```
my_colors = list(islice(cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'c', 'm', 
                              'tan', 'grey', 'pink', 'chocolate', 'gold']), None, len(df)))

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 12), dpi = 200)
i = 0
for key, value in zip(per.keys(), per.values):
    if (value > 0):
        ax.bar(key, value, label=key, color = my_colors)
        ax.text(i, value + 0.5, str(np.round(value, 2)), ha='center')
        i = i + 1
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([]) 
plt.title('NaN Value percentage in the dataset')
plt.ylim(0,115)
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: NaN]

Any help is appreciated.

See the data [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-lyuCzdemwZMph9n?e=MKwfgc).

Comment: Note that the idea to use 40 visually distinct colors won't work well.  Colors will also be quite similar.  Also, working with an indirection via a legend to find out which bar goes with which name should be avoided here.  You could create horizontal bars, and then put each name next to the corresponding bar.  (Adding some test data to the post would make it much easier to answer.)

Comment: Okay let me add some test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems with your second code:

```
my_colors = list(islice(cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'c', 'm', 
                              'tan', 'grey', 'pink', 'chocolate', 'gold']), None, len(df)))
```

Here `len(df)` gets you the number of rows, but you actually want a list that is equal to the number of per.keys(). So: `len(per.keys())`. Next, you need to use your variable `i` to iterate over your list of colors.

```
ax.bar(key, value, label=key, color = my_colors)
```

Here, I think you need to use `my_colors[i]`.

Incidentally, using [matplotlib.cm.get_cmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap) on matplotlib's [Colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) is great to get you a list of unique colors from a palette quickly. Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import random
import string

# build df with some random NaNs
data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(5,20))
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], data.shape, p=[.4, .6]).astype(bool)
data[mask] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:20])

per = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100

length = len(per.keys())
cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma', length)

lst = [*range(length)]
random.shuffle(lst)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 12), dpi = 200)
i = 0
for key, value in zip(per.keys(), per.values):
    if (value > 0):
        ax.bar(key, value, label=key, color = cmap(lst[i])[:3])
        ax.text(i, value + 0.5, str(np.round(value, 2)), ha='center')
        i = i + 1
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([]) 
plt.title('NaN Value percentage in the dataset')
plt.ylim(0,115)
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or non-random (comment out `random.shuffle(lst)`):

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed. Muchas gracias amigo :)